# how can i modify a csv file to add new header using bash command?

Tags: bash, shell

Hi currently i have a csv file . i want to add a new header field named budget and values as True for all records. here is my csv file.

```
id,address1,address2,address3,address4,addressprofile,administrator,averageclickthroughrate,contactnumber,contractid,country,createdby,createdon,currency,customercontactnumber,customerid,defaultlanguage,features,internal,inventories,lastupdated,lastupdatedby,logo,name,status,testmessagecontactlist,testmessagelimit,usedefaultclickthroughrate,zipcode
d4385ff7-247f-407a-97c6-366d8128c6c7,,,,,eb0137fc-b279-11e8-8753-570ce0b5ef9b,92059277-e2ad-4cf0-a941-0f0b52bf3421,40,,,,ab4e0287-6973-4eec-bd03-cf3669c535d0,2019-01-08 08:48:36.353+0000,,,,b04265e6-c114-470c-8bb0-d10879655ec9,[],True,"[bdf7fad0-b8cd-4a9a-9c9d-48261fd5e7c7, be25104b-90d1-4076-bb4b-44c756d06d20]",2019-04-05 09:38:15.322+0000,3363a3ad-f52a-4a8b-bc52-7a069bab31d9,,OTT,ACTIVE,ca6b6808-111c-49ac-90ac-44078e8e3db0,5,True,
```

this is the following result i am expecting.

```
id,address1,address2,address3,address4,addressprofile,administrator,averageclickthroughrate,budget,contactnumber,contractid,country,createdby,createdon,currency,customercontactnumber,customerid,defaultlanguage,features,internal,inventories,lastupdated,lastupdatedby,logo,name,status,testmessagecontactlist,testmessagelimit,usedefaultclickthroughrate,zipcode
d4385ff7-247f-407a-97c6-366d8128c6c7,,,,,eb0137fc-b279-11e8-8753-570ce0b5ef9b,92059277-e2ad-4cf0-a941-0f0b52bf3421,40,,True,,,ab4e0287-6973-4eec-bd03-cf3669c535d0,2019-01-08 08:48:36.353+0000,,,,b04265e6-c114-470c-8bb0-d10879655ec9,[],True,"[bdf7fad0-b8cd-4a9a-9c9d-48261fd5e7c7, be25104b-90d1-4076-bb4b-44c756d06d20]",2019-04-05 09:38:15.322+0000,3363a3ad-f52a-4a8b-bc52-7a069bab31d9,,OTT,ACTIVE,ca6b6808-111c-49ac-90ac-44078e8e3db0,5,True,
```

how can i do using shell scripting
thank you

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/11/awk-examples-insert-remove-update-fields.html

Comment: thank you so much i think what i want is add a value after 8th  column for all the lines , probably awk command will be good enough. thank you for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk can easily do the job, similar to @kvantour link:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS = OFS = ","} {$8 = $8 FS (NR == 1 ? "budget" : "true")}1'
```

where `FS`: field separator, `OFS`: output field separator, `NR`: current row number

Example: https://ideone.com/oRQqhi